# Make a backup copy of several files matching a pattern

Tags: shell, backup

I have files: `x0001_test.xml z0054_test.xml k5487_test.xml`....

I would like to save them doing something like: `cp *_test.xml ${BEGINNING}_test.xml.SAVE`.

Is there a way in bash script to store the content of `*` for each file in order to re-inject it after? Or should I use a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop to do that is probably trivial enough to not need a separate one-line command. You don't need to save a *portion* of the filename since you're just adding `.SAVE` to the *whole* thing:

```
for fspec in *_test.xml; do
    cp "${fspec}" "${fspec}.SAVE"
done
```

And, in any case, you can do it in one line if you really want:

```
for fspec in *_test.xml; do cp "${fspec}" "${fspec}.SAVE" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

@paxdiablo gave you the most straightforward answer. Another couple of options

```
printf "%s\0" *_test.xml | xargs -0 -L1 -I{}  cp {} {}.SAVE
```

```
find . -name \*_test.xml -exec  cp {} {}.SAVE \;
```

This assumes you have GNU xargs, and the find command may find matching files in subdirectories.